# Check if product(s) are in cart of a specific category

Tags: cartthrob, conditionals, mightybigrobot

I am looking for a way to check if certain products of a specific category are in cart and then based on that hide a specific payment method.

I have found this [thread](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/1747/in-cartthrob-how-can-i-determine-whether-a-specific-product-is-in-cart-already) which deals with basically the same problem but checks if a certain product is in cart.

I'd like to tackle this with a broader approach, thus aiming for categories since products can be added all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using Stash. I now check for certain channels that contain products where payment with PayPal isn't allowed.

It goes like this:

```
{exp:stash:set name="is_channel" parse_tags="yes" parse_conditionals="yes" default="0"}
    {exp:cartthrob:cart_items_info}
        {if channel_name == "channel_a"}1{/if}
        {if channel_name == "channel_b"}1{/if}
        {if channel_name == "channel_c"}1{/if}
    {/exp:cartthrob:cart_items_info}
{/exp:stash:set}
```

then in the template code:

```
{exp:stash:parse process="end"}
    {if {exp:stash:is_empty name="is_channel"}}
        Content here
    {/if}
{/exp:stash:parse}
```